# Cannot convert from string to int using stoi

Tags: c++, vector, casting

In my program first I read a file into a vector of strings called `rosterList`:

> 100
>
> 95
>
> 0
>
> -1
>
> 110
>
> 80
>
> 90
>
> -1
>
> 120
>
> 80
>
> 75
>
> -1
>
> 130
>
> 60
>
> 55
>
> -1

This step is successful. My goal is to create a vector of `Student` objects using the data above. Constructor accepts 3 strings as parameters:

```
Student::Student(string id,string g1,string g2)
```

To do that, the program loops through this vector of strings line by line, if the line converted to integer is greater or equal to 100, it is an id, then dynamically create a new `Student` object by passing the id (current line) and the next 2 lines as parameters, and add the object to the vector `studentRecords`

```
for (vector<string>::iterator it = rosterList.begin(); it<rosterList.end();it++){
        if(stoi(*it)>=100 || it == rosterList.begin()){ // error
            studentRecords.push_back(
                 Student(*it,*(it+1),*(it+2)) // dynamically push 
            );
        }
    }
```

And there is a dynamic error:

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   std::invalid_argument: stoi: no conversion

I looked it up online, the error comes from `stoi` not be able to convert. Where in the program goes wrong?

Comment: Maybe you read empty lines too and you're feeding them to `stoi`?

Comment: During development and debug, you should always echo all inputs. I would guess you have a  problem with your cin statements, (which is code you do not present).  Please review [MCVE], and update to show some minimal code we can look at, or at least explain why you think it works.  Can you dump the rosterList?

Comment: "Where in the program goes wrong?" This would be a perfect time to start learning how to use your debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you have to read your file correctly....or
If you are not confident on file data, do a validation for numeric content.
Below is code sample.
Any junk that you read other than numeric content in your file will cause failure.
Below code compiles and for your idea. You can optimize it.

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <cstring>
    #include <vector>
    #include <string>
    #include <algorithm>

    using namespace std;

std::vector<string> rosterList;
bool is_numeric(string strin)
{
    char const *str = strin.c_str();
    return all_of(str, str+strlen(str), 
                       [](unsigned char c) { return ::isdigit(c); });
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    rosterList.push_back("100");
    rosterList.push_back(" ");
    rosterList.push_back("140");
    rosterList.push_back("180");


for (vector<string>::iterator it = rosterList.begin(); it<rosterList.end();it++){
        if(is_numeric(*it) && (stoi(*it)>=100 || it == rosterList.begin())){ // error

         std::cout<<stoi(*it)<<std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I saw @pzelasko comment before seeing your answer and something similar to `is_numeric` is exactly what I added to my program. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One problem I see in your code is that you're accessing `it+1` and `it+2` also when `it` is the last 2 positions of the vector. This will try to access a pointer that doesn't exist as this points to after `rosterList.end()`.

You will have to test if `it+1` and `it+2` are `<` than `rosterList.end()` before using them.

Comment: Luckily in his code it is "-1" last element so if statement will fail. But when at 55 (last but one).... *(it +1) is "-1" and (*it+2) is trying to deference the end()... I have to check what happens if we dereference "end()". I never tried it.